# Bad practice to initialize and calculate in a single variable? Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, variables, initialization, arithmetic-expressions

Is it bad practice to initialize and do arithmetic within a variable? i.e say I have multiple rooms of different area dimensions that I must find the area of:

(example in feet)

```
double room_area1 = 9.5 * 6.8;
double room_area2 = 9.1 * 6.2;
double room_area3 = 10.0 * 7.1;
```

Or is it best to do:

```
double room_area1 = 9.5;
room_area1 = room_area1 * 6.8;
```

Is there any disparity between the two ways here or is it the same thing and just a matter of style?

Comment: Note: C and C++ are case sensitive -- you need to use `double`, not `Double` (unless you're defining a type of your own named `Double`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Apologies. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First involves only one operation: **Initialization**,
While second involves two operations: **Initialization + Assignment**.

For an intrinsic data type like `double` the overhead is negligible but for user defined data types second is detrimental to performance(*How much? Profiling should tell that*).

So in general it is better practice to use First because:

- It is guaranteed to be atleast as fast if not faster than Second
- It is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The first way is better. Reason: it's more readable.

While it is correct, that these constructions are semantically different, **for simple types** the compiler will almost certainly optimize the second case to be like the first case, and generate the same machine code, storing a constant (calculated at compile-time) into `room_area1`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the first examples. In fact it's better that way because you can declare the variable const.